# Session variables and back button

Tags: asp.net

Please see the code below:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Session("Test") = Request.QueryString("ID")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.Write(Session("Test"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please follow the following steps:

> 1) Go to Default.aspx?id=1
>       2) Click the button
>       3) Go to Default.aspx?id=2
>       4) Click the button
>       5) Use the back button to go back to step 1
>       6) Click the button

Is there any scenario where the ID after step 6 can be 2 instead of 1? I am trying to trap a bug.  I don't think it can be because the button starts the ASP.NET lifecycle and the page init is executed first.

Answer (score 0):

No. On every page request (e.g. clicks) the page fires its Init event - means the session variable is assigned the value from the URL string.

What can happen though (at least I think so, please verify this!) is that your browser keeps the previous version in cache, so when you click the back button, it probably may display a wrong value. However, after refresh it should work as expected. Try to debug your website using VS to see the actual values stored in your variables.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you confirm what you mean by "refresh".  Would clicking the button "refresh"?

Comment: @w0051977, yes, right next to the 'back' button in your browser :) Or simply F5 on your keyboard. If you're not sure which event happens first, use the debugging feature in your VS and monitor the steps to see what happens.

Comment: ctrl+f5, f5 alone can still load a cached version